# What's the deal with the JQuery constructor?  Also, I'm confused about the DOM tree.  And, it looks like I don't know what the jQuery object is

Tags: jquery, dom

Assuming that is even the correct term, what's the deal with them?

```
jQuery("#removeUser", jQuery(myform)).click(
    function()
    {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    });
```

So, in the above code, there appears to be a need for 2 arguments in the constructor.  The first parameter takes the id of an HTML element called "removeUser" and the other is actually var which is a string of a whole collection of HTML elements and their nested children.

Basically, what the above code does is remove a form when someone clicks the "removeUser" button.  I copied the original code and modified it, and although it works (to some extent) I don't entirely understand what's happening here.

When I tried to create the new jQuery instance using only "#removeUser" element, I didn't get the results that I wanted.  Instead of only removing one "user" it removed all of them.  So, there's something happening here that I don't understand at all.

So, inside the function, who is "`this`"?  Is it the removeUser element or is it the string?  I'm so confused!

============

## UPDATE:

So, based on Cory's and Torsten Walter's comment, I could give the jQuery "constructor" something like the following:

```
    jQuery("#removeUser", "<tr name=parent1><td>User: </td><td name=parent2><button id=\"removeUser\">remove</button></td></tr>").click(
    function()
    {
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    }
);
```

Or, the following, for those who don't like to use "jQuery":

```
    $("#removeUser", "<tr name=parent1><td>User: </td><td name=parent2><button id=\"removeUser\">remove</button></td></tr>").click(
    function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    }
);
```

Also, I noticed that some people don't like my use of non-unique ID's, so I could have something like:

```
    $("button", "<tr name=parent1><td>User: </td><td name=parent2><button>remove</button></td></tr>").click(
    function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    }
);
```

Since, every "user" only has one button anyways.

Also, some people suggest that I use a class instead.  Along with the advice of NOT using the second argument, it wouldn't give me the results that I wanted.

```
    $(".removeUser", "<tr name=parent1><td>User: </td><td name=parent2><button class=\"removeUser\">remove</button></td></tr>").click(
    function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
    }
);
```

The above would remove *all* "users", which isn't what I want.

============

## UPDATE:

Also, what I have with the "parent1" and "parent2" thing is wrong, right?  It isn't actually accessing parent1 at all is it?

What I actually have for myform is the following:

```
var myform = "<table>"+ //<---parent 1, right?
                    "  <tr>" + //<--parent 2?
                    "     <td>User " + jQuerycountForms + ":</td>" + 
                    "     <td>UserID:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                    "     <td><input type='text' name='UserID["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></td>" + 
                    "     <td>Roles:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                    "     <td><textarea name='Roles["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></textarea></td>" + 
                    "     <td><button id=\"removeUser\" onclick=\"jQuerycountForms--;\">remove</button></td>" + //Or, is that "td" parent2?
                    "  </tr><br/>"+
                    "</table>";
```

In my HTML I have something like the following:

```
<div id="container">
            <table>
                <tr>
        <td><button id="addUser" type="button">add</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

What the "addUser" button does is it adds another user.  There's some jQuery javascript which executes the adding of a new user attached to this element.

When I tried to get rid of the outer `table` element for the `myform` variable, I got a problem whenever I clicked the removed the user.  What ended up happening was that I ended up removing the entire first table.

So, the following value for `myform`:

```
    var myform = "  <tr>" + //Now the "table" element shown earlier in the HTML is parent1!
                    "     <td>User " + jQuerycountForms + ":</td>" + 
                    "     <td>UserID:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                    "     <td><input type='text' name='UserID["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></td>" + 
                    "     <td>Roles:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                    "     <td><textarea name='Roles["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></textarea></td>" + 
                    "     <td><button id=\"removeUser\" onclick=\"jQuerycountForms--;\">remove</button></td>" + 
                    "  </tr><br/>";
```

would cause there to be no more `add` button anymore.

So, who are `removeUser` button's parents?  Which one is the closest parent, and who is the parent of that?

Since, it's Javascript, I can't actually see what changes are being made to the HTML.  If this was Java rendering this, the changes would be reflected in the HTML source.  But, with this, it's like I'm left with my imagination to figure things out.  And, if you're not too familiar with Javascript then it can be kind of difficult to see what's happening.

============

## UPDATE:

So, my guess as to what the HTML might look like after I click one user is:

```
        <div id="container">
            <table>
        <tr>
        <td><button id="addUser" type="button">add</button></td>
        <table> <!-- Well, I'm definitely the grand parent. -->
            <tr> <!-- But, am I anyone's parent? -->
                <td>User 0:</td>
                <td>UserID:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='UserID[0]'></td>
                <td>Roles:&nbsp;</td>
                <td><textarea name='Roles[0]'></textarea></td>
                <td> <!-- Or, am I the daddy? -->
                    <button id=removeUser onclick="jQuerycountForms--;">remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr><br/>
                    </table>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**So, basically, the second part of my question is, "Who is the first parent accessed (parent2)?"  Is it the `td` or the `tr` element?  Why doesn't it think that `tr` is a parent of `td`?  It certainly looks like it is.**

============

## UPDATE:

This is in response to Cory's jsFiddle link (thanks, btw, that appears to be a useful tool).  The following code showed the structure

```
var button = $('.removeUser');
alert("Me = " + button[0].tagName); //button
alert("Parent = " + button.parent()[0].tagName); // td
alert("Grand-Parent = " + button.parent().parent()[0].tagName); // tr
alert("Great Grand-Parent = " + button.parent().parent().parent()[0].tagName); // tbody
alert("Great, Great Grand-Parent = " + button.parent().parent().parent().parent()[0].tagName); // table
```

So, let me get this straight.  If this were a real OOP kind of language, then we'd have something like the following:

```
Jquery button = new Jquery('.removeUser');
```

This `jQuery` "class" would really be a collection of some kind, but, apparently, with only one member in it?  The single member has attributes such as "tagName" along with other attributes.

However, the jQuery class itself has methods which allow the user to navigate the DOM tree (relative to the root of this tree).

I figured out that if I had two "removeUser" buttons, then I could use an array notation for button[1] as well.   But, of course, you can't have more than one parent so anything with `parent()[1]` wouldn't work.

Ordinarily, I would have assumed that jQuery owned the "tagName" property, but it looks like that isn't the case.  Instead, that property belongs to this array's member.  Anyways, how do I look up what attributes that these array members own?

Comment: First page of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). The second parameter provides the selection context, thus improving speed because the function doesn't have to search the whole document but only a subtree. Also this inside a jQuery event or loop refers to the current element ( in the list / the event is invoked on ).

Comment: You basically just disregarded everyones help. Why are you still trying to pass $() 2 parameters? You don't need to.

Comment: You can't go from `<tr>` to `<button>`. You need to add a `<td>` around it.

Comment: @jao:  For the first, "add" button you mean?  Right, I'll fix that.

Comment: Yes I meant the first button but if you'd like to nest a table inside another table the closing `</td>` after the first </table> and remove the <br />

Comment: +1 for the longest question TITLE ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(foo, bar)` is more or less just syntatic sugar for `$(bar).find(foo)`. `$(bar)` itself has three quite different meanings depending on the type of `bar`:

- if `bar` is a function, run it as soon as the document loaded;
- if it is a string with HTML tags in it, create a DOM fragment (basically a piece of a web page, but not attached to the current page, just floating in the air) out of it
- otherwise treat it as a selector and try to find matching elements on the current page.

So what `$("#removeUser", "<tr>...</tr>").click(...)` does is create a new `tr` element with the given contents, select the element with the right id from inside it, and attach a click handler to it. Unless you later append the element to the current page, this will have no effect whatsoever, as you are doing staff to a detached element which is not part of the page.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside the `function() { }` is the element that was clicked. Since you've bound the click event to an element with the id "removeUser", that's the element to which `this` will refer in the click event handler. `jQuery(this).parent().parent()` is likely grabbing the form element, but that depends on how your form is built and where the "removeUser" element is within the form.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things before I explain the code: you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` unless you're in no-conflict mode to shorten up your code.

```
var myform = '#something'; // not sure what this should be
$("#removeUser", $(myform)).click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
});
```

*What I see is this:*

Within the `$(myform)` element, search for and bind a click event to the `#removeUser` element. The `this` inside the click event function is the DOM element whose ID is `#removeUser` (not a jQuery object). You are asking for its parent's parent and attempting to remove it from the DOM.

You do *not* need two arguments in the jQuery function. You can provide a second to limit the context to where jQuery should try apply the selector you gave it. But, since you shouldn't have more than one `removeUser` ID on the page, you could eliminate the second parameter, and clean it up by simplifying the form-removal code:

```
$("#removeUser").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form:first').remove();
    // or $(this).closest('form').remove(); as others have suggested
});
```

**UPDATE**:

Given that the true "user" container here is a table row (`<tr>`), here's how I would change the above example:

First, change your `myform` code a little bit so that your button and table rows use class names (not for CSS, but merely for jQuery to be able to select them using something other than an ID):

```
var myform = "<table>" + 
                "  <tr class=\"userRow\">" + 
                "     <td>User " + jQuerycountForms + ":</td>" + 
                "     <td>UserID:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                "     <td><input type='text' name='UserID["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></td>" + 
                "     <td>Roles:&nbsp;</td>" + 
                "     <td><textarea name='Roles["+jQuerycountForms+"]'></textarea></td>" + 
                "     <td><button class=\"removeUser\" onclick=\"jQuerycountForms--;\">remove</button></td>" + 
                "  </tr><br/>"+
                "</table>";
```

Regarding the parent structure: relative to the `<button>`, its surrounding `<td>` is the *first* parent. The `<td>`'s parent is the `<tr>` (second parent), and the `<tr>`'s parent is the `<table>` (third parent). As I said, I changed the above to use class names, so you can forget about the parent structure. Let jQuery dig through the hierarchy for you.

The JS you would use to bind the "remove user" event then changes to:

```
$('.removeUser').click(function() { // ID selector changed to class selector
    $(this).parents('tr.userRow').remove();
});
```

Technically you could forget about adding the "userRow" class to the `<tr>` and just use:

```
$('.removeUser').click(function() { // ID selector changed to class selector
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Short and sweet. No `.parent()` guesswork, no worrying about duplicate IDs, and it's easily maintainable.

Comment: I do.  Every time a "user" is generated on the form, there is a button whose id is "removeUser".  The `myform` variable contains some text where the `removeUser` button resides.  If I didn't give each user its own `removeUser` button, then I could do without the second argument?  But, since I don't, I have to give it the second argument to give it some context?

Comment: Since you have multiple `removeUser` buttons, you should add a `removeUser` class to each and remove the id. Then you would use `.removeUser` instead of `#removeUser`.

Comment: @user919860: Ideally you would fix your code so that it generates unique ids no matter what, or, applies a class to the button instead (e.g. ".removeUser"). `closest()`, from the button's perspective, will find only the form in which the button resides, and thus you still wouldn't need to provide jQuery with a second parameter.

Comment: But, if I do that, then I would have to make sure that I include the second argument, right?  Otherwise, all users will be removed.

Comment: @Cory That didn't work.  All that it did was remove ALL users.

Comment: @user919860: What comprises a "user"? Just a text box? Do you have one form per user, or all users in one form? EDIT: I just saw you're updates. The second parameter to `$()` needs to be an element that already exists; you can't supply a new HTML structure as a string. You could give each of your `<tr>` rows a class, and then find and remove the row to remove the "user".

Comment: So, if what you said about the parents is true, then why do you think that the one that is closed is the `table` element?  $(this).parent().parent() should be the TR and getting rid of the inner `table` shouldn't cause the entire form to disappear.  But, it still does.  Why is the great-grandparent being accessed through ".parent().parent()"?  Shouldn't it be ".parent().parent().parent()" instead if I actually wanted the table to disappear?

Comment: @user919860: Check and see what this script produces for you: http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/bnbAJ/. I'm seeing "TD" for the first parent, "TR" for the second, "TBODY" for the third, and "TABLE" for the fourth, on Chrome. You may be seeing different results in different browsers. This is just another reason for using `.parents('tr')` or `.closest('tr')`.

Comment: @user919860: Also, unrelated, but you should remove the trailing `<br/>` after the `</tr>` in the `myform` variable, and also add `type="button"` to your `<button>`. Without the type specified, IE treats them as `type="submit"`, which you probably do not want.

Comment: Why did you use the "[0]" next to every object before you accessed `tagName`?  LOL.  What are these things anyways.  I read somewhere that "objects" in javascript were really associative arrays, but I don't see why you're using array notation now, except for that it appears to be required.  I couldn't get `tagName` without using the array notation.  I'm just confused as to why that matters.

Comment: @user919860: `$()` always returns an array, but it's a special jQuery array. It walks and talks like a regular array though. Its comprised of the DOM elements it finds using the selector you give it. `[0]` accesses the first element in the array, which is a DOM element and is not wrapped by jQuery. `tagName` is a property on HTML elements. And you've got it backwards: you can fake an associative array using a JS object, but natively, JS has no such thing as an associative array (like PHP).

Comment: How do I look up what are the members of the HTML "class" or whatever the correct term is?

Comment: @user919860: Are you using `.parents('tr')` or `.closest('tr')`? Try the latter. You might have to do `.parents('tr:first')` to get it to work right otherwise (as it might be removing *all* `<tr>` parents instead of just the first).

Answer (score 1):

Lets clean up your code first:

```
$("#removeUser").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('form').remove(); 
});
```

You don't need the second param for the jQuery selector, the `this` will refer to the object you pass it, which in this case is the html element `#removeUser`.

`closest()` will search up the DOM until it finds the first element you give it. I'm just assuming you're looking for the first instance of form here.

I'm not sure if this is the case, but it sounds like you have a form for each user you're displaying on the page and inside each form you have a button for removing them. If that is the case then you should use a class for `removeUser` instead of an Id. Then the my code would work fine still because the `this` would be the button you clicked and it would search from that button until it found the form that button was in and only remove that form.

Answer (score 1):

You are rightfully confused. The code doesn't really make any sense.

Id's must be unique, so there is no reason to filter remove user to a particular form because it won't work, it will just select the first element on the page with the given id.

The below code will do the same thing that your code does.

```
jQuery("#removeUser").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().parent().remove(); 
});
```

The `.parent().parent()` part should probably be `jQuery(this).closest("form");` or `jQuery(this).closest("tr");` etc.

If you do infact have duplicate ID's, simply replace `id="removeUser"` with `class="removeUser"` and then use `.removeUser` instead of `#removeUser` in the snippet I provided.